# Translating timestamp to Human Readable format

Tags: python, date, time, timezone

I am trying to make sense of timestamps from all over the world to make it a bit more intuitive what is going on. Here's an example:

```
releaseDate: "2002-08-22T07:00:00Z" # only possible date format
```

To the best of my knowledge, the date would be interpreted as: `"2002-08-22 at 7a GMT"`. Is this the correct reading of the above? Additionally, is there a library or something similar where it could tell me (approximately) which country this would be applicable to, that is, where the TimeZone is +7 GMT. For example, in the above, it could be read as:

```
"2002-08-22 in Los Angeles, CA"
```

[image]

This would be the most useful way (in my case) to read the above. What would be the best way to accomplish the above?

Comment: python-dateutil can handle timezones well ... that + strftime

Comment: let [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) be your friend

Comment: That is an iso8601 date string, the time is utc, what other formats are possible?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes it is. The 'releaseDate' means the time it was released in a particular country. The actual release will always be at midnight, so in the above case, I'm looking to make sense of what country (or a similar country with the same timezone) it is released in.

Comment: @David542 so the time is always zulu time?

Comment: @David542 there is a number of countries having the same time zone, how do you want to select one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: Be sure to read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially "time zone != offset".  Though Padraic is right - the only offset you have is `Z` which is shorthand for `+00:00`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the times are all zulu times then there is nothing to parse from it in relation to a timezone your date string is not `utc+7` it is utc at `7am`.  , if you wanted to find what time it was in other timezones using the utc time you could use the `pytz` lib:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
_utc = pytz.utc

dte = "2002-08-22T07:00:00Z"
utc = datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").replace(tzinfo=_utc)
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    tz = timezone(tz)
    print(tz)
    print(utc.astimezone(tz))
```

If you wanted to find the timezones where it was midnight based on your utc time:

```
dte = "2002-08-22T07:00:00Z"
print( datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
utc = datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").replace(tzinfo=_utc)
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    tz = timezone(tz)
    dt = (utc.astimezone(tz))
    if str(dt.time()) == "00:00:00":
        print(tz)
        print(dt)
```

Which would output:

```
America/Creston
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Dawson
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Dawson_Creek
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Ensenada
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Hermosillo
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Los_Angeles
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Phoenix
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Santa_Isabel
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Tijuana
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Vancouver
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
America/Whitehorse
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
Canada/Pacific
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
Canada/Yukon
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
Etc/GMT+7
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
MST
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
Mexico/BajaNorte
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
PST8PDT
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
US/Arizona
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
US/Pacific
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
US/Pacific-New
2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00
```

If the offset was specified it would be like above `2002-08-22 00:00:00-07:00` or `2002-08-22 00:00:00+07:00`. You could also just create a database using offsets to group and use the time to see which offset to look in to find the zones that it would be midnight.

If you want the two letter country codes:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone, country_timezones, utc

_utc = utc
dte = "2002-08-22T10:00:00Z"
utc = datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").replace(tzinfo=_utc)
coun_to_tz = {tz: coun for coun, v in country_timezones.items() for tz in v}

for _tz, coun in coun_to_tz.items():
    tz = timezone(_tz)
    dt = utc.astimezone(tz)
    if str(dt.time()) == "00:00:00":
        print(coun)
        print(dt)
        print(_tz)
```

Output:

```
CK
2002-08-22 00:00:00-10:00
Pacific/Rarotonga
PF
2002-08-22 00:00:00-10:00
Pacific/Tahiti
UM
2002-08-22 00:00:00-10:00
Pacific/Johnston
KI
2002-08-23 00:00:00+14:00
Pacific/Kiritimati
US
2002-08-22 00:00:00-10:00
Pacific/Honolulu
```

I used a different utc start time so the output is different.

I pulled the ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 English country names and code elements s from [here](http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-list/r/data.json) and created a single dict mapping two letter code to full country name so at least the output will be a bit more understandable:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

_utc = utc
dte = "2002-08-22T10:00:00Z"
utc = datetime.strptime(dte, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").replace(tzinfo=_utc)
coun_to_tz = {'Europe/Helsinki': 'Finland', 'Asia/Thimphu': 'Bhutan', 'Australia/Currie': 'Australia', 'Pacific/Niue': 'Niue', 'Asia/Dili': 'Timor-Leste', 'Europe/Kiev': 'Ukraine', 'Indian/Mahe': 'Seychelles', 'Asia/Kathmandu': 'Nepal', 'Asia/Aden': 'Yemen', 'Europe/Malta': 'Malta', 'Pacific/Noumea': 'New Caledonia', 'America/Bahia_Banderas': 'Mexico', 'Africa/Ceuta': 'Spain', 'Europe/Uzhgorod': 'Ukraine', 'Asia/Hebron': 'Palestine, State of', 'America/Indiana/Knox': 'United States', 'Europe/Kaliningrad': 'Russian Federation', 'America/Chicago': 'United States', 'Asia/Amman': 'Jordan', 'Europe/Isle_of_Man': 'Isle of Man', 'America/Guadeloupe': 'Guadeloupe', 'Europe/Copenhagen': 'Denmark', 'Indian/Maldives': 'Maldives', 'Pacific/Bougainville': 'Papua New Guinea', 'Africa/Banjul': 'Gambia', 'America/Cuiaba': 'Brazil', 'Pacific/Wake': 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', 'Antarctica/Mawson': 'Antarctica', 'America/Noronha': 'Brazil', 'America/Indiana/Tell_City': 'United States', 'America/Inuvik': 'Canada', 'Africa/Niamey': 'Niger', 'Africa/Juba': 'South Sudan', 'Atlantic/Reykjavik': 'Iceland', 'America/Curacao': 'Curaçao', 'Africa/Porto-Novo': 'Benin', 'Africa/Brazzaville': 'Congo', 'Atlantic/South_Georgia': 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', 'Asia/Baku': 'Azerbaijan', 'America/Detroit': 'United States', 'America/Monterrey': 'Mexico', 'America/Grenada': 'Grenada', 'Australia/Perth': 'Australia', 'Asia/Magadan': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Fiji': 'Fiji', 'Pacific/Honolulu': 'United States', 'America/Thule': 'Greenland', 'America/Guyana': 'Guyana', 'America/Grand_Turk': 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'America/Indiana/Petersburg': 'United States', 'Antarctica/Rothera': 'Antarctica', 'Europe/Vatican': 'Holy See (Vatican City State)', 'America/Cambridge_Bay': 'Canada', 'America/Marigot': 'Saint Martin (French part)', 'Africa/Sao_Tome': 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Pacific/Palau': 'Palau', 'Asia/Gaza': 'Palestine, State of', 'America/Tortola': 'Virgin Islands, British', 'Asia/Yakutsk': 'Russian Federation', 'America/Argentina/Catamarca': 'Argentina', 'Pacific/Norfolk': 'Norfolk Island', 'America/Paramaribo': 'Suriname', 'Asia/Aqtobe': 'Kazakhstan', 'America/Anguilla': 'Anguilla', 'Africa/Douala': 'Cameroon', 'Asia/Chita': 'Russian Federation', 'Asia/Riyadh': 'Saudi Arabia', 'Africa/Mbabane': 'Swaziland', 'America/Argentina/San_Juan': 'Argentina', 'Europe/London': 'United Kingdom', 'Australia/Brisbane': 'Australia', 'Asia/Urumqi': 'China', 'America/Asuncion': 'Paraguay', 'America/Regina': 'Canada', 'Asia/Qyzylorda': 'Kazakhstan', 'Africa/Kigali': 'Rwanda', 'Africa/Dakar': 'Senegal', 'Asia/Jerusalem': 'Israel', 'Asia/Ashgabat': 'Turkmenistan', 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur': 'Malaysia', 'Africa/Maputo': 'Mozambique', 'America/Glace_Bay': 'Canada', 'Africa/Malabo': 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Europe/Jersey': 'Jersey', 'America/Rankin_Inlet': 'Canada', 'America/Fortaleza': 'Brazil', 'Europe/Luxembourg': 'Luxembourg', 'Asia/Taipei': 'Taiwan, Province of China', 'Europe/Bratislava': 'Slovakia', 'Asia/Pontianak': 'Indonesia', 'Pacific/Chuuk': 'Micronesia, Federated States of', 'Indian/Chagos': 'British Indian Ocean Territory', 'America/Cayman': 'Cayman Islands', 'Atlantic/Madeira': 'Portugal', 'Africa/El_Aaiun': 'Western Sahara', 'America/Indiana/Winamac': 'United States', 'America/St_Kitts': 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Asia/Tbilisi': 'Georgia', 'America/Yellowknife': 'Canada', 'Atlantic/St_Helena': 'Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha', 'Asia/Novokuznetsk': 'Russian Federation', 'Africa/Libreville': 'Gabon', 'Europe/Brussels': 'Belgium', 'America/Guatemala': 'Guatemala', 'Europe/Simferopol': 'Russian Federation', 'Europe/Vaduz': 'Liechtenstein', 'Africa/Harare': 'Zimbabwe', 'America/Goose_Bay': 'Canada', 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis': 'United States', 'Africa/Cairo': 'Egypt', 'Asia/Bishkek': 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Asia/Sakhalin': 'Russian Federation', 'Asia/Nicosia': 'Cyprus', 'America/St_Thomas': 'Virgin Islands, U.S.', 'Europe/Sarajevo': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Pacific/Johnston': 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde': 'Cape Verde', 'America/Tegucigalpa': 'Honduras', 'Australia/Eucla': 'Australia', 'Pacific/Tahiti': 'French Polynesia', 'Africa/Tripoli': 'Libya', 'Australia/Sydney': 'Australia', 'America/Kentucky/Monticello': 'United States', 'Antarctica/Palmer': 'Antarctica', 'Asia/Tokyo': 'Japan', 'Asia/Baghdad': 'Iraq', 'America/Dawson_Creek': 'Canada', 'America/Bogota': 'Colombia', 'Pacific/Chatham': 'New Zealand', 'America/Scoresbysund': 'Greenland', 'Pacific/Pitcairn': 'Pitcairn', 'Europe/Madrid': 'Spain', 'America/Ojinaga': 'Mexico', 'America/Campo_Grande': 'Brazil', 'America/Lima': 'Peru', 'America/Metlakatla': 'United States', 'America/Boise': 'United States', 'Atlantic/Bermuda': 'Bermuda', 'America/Kralendijk': 'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba', 'America/Edmonton': 'Canada', 'Asia/Kabul': 'Afghanistan', 'America/Maceio': 'Brazil', 'Europe/Stockholm': 'Sweden', 'Asia/Oral': 'Kazakhstan', 'Pacific/Efate': 'Vanuatu', 'Europe/Athens': 'Greece', 'Europe/Rome': 'Italy', 'America/St_Lucia': 'Saint Lucia', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa': 'Ethiopia', 'Asia/Aqtau': 'Kazakhstan', 'America/Indiana/Marengo': 'United States', 'America/Port_of_Spain': 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Africa/Lubumbashi': 'Congo, the Democratic Republic of the', 'America/Moncton': 'Canada', 'Africa/Bangui': 'Central African Republic', 'Asia/Samarkand': 'Uzbekistan', 'America/Cayenne': 'French Guiana', 'Europe/Zurich': 'Switzerland', 'America/Adak': 'United States', 'America/Argentina/San_Luis': 'Argentina', 'America/Mexico_City': 'Mexico', 'Australia/Lindeman': 'Australia', 'Pacific/Funafuti': 'Tuvalu', 'Asia/Jayapura': 'Indonesia', 'Pacific/Saipan': 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'America/Santo_Domingo': 'Dominican Republic', 'Africa/Freetown': 'Sierra Leone', 'America/Aruba': 'Aruba', 'Asia/Yekaterinburg': 'Russian Federation', 'Europe/Ljubljana': 'Slovenia', 'America/Iqaluit': 'Canada', 'America/Caracas': 'Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of', 'Europe/Zaporozhye': 'Ukraine', 'Indian/Christmas': 'Christmas Island', 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk': 'Russian Federation', 'America/Los_Angeles': 'United States', 'America/St_Vincent': 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Europe/Prague': 'Czech Republic', 'Africa/Monrovia': 'Liberia', 'Africa/Gaborone': 'Botswana', 'America/Cancun': 'Mexico', 'Pacific/Wallis': 'Wallis and Futuna', 'Asia/Qatar': 'Qatar', 'Asia/Bahrain': 'Bahrain', 'America/Boa_Vista': 'Brazil', 'America/Santa_Isabel': 'Mexico', 'Antarctica/Macquarie': 'Australia', 'America/Eirunepe': 'Brazil', 'America/Guayaquil': 'Ecuador', 'Africa/Accra': 'Ghana', 'America/Matamoros': 'Mexico', 'Africa/Conakry': 'Guinea', 'America/Araguaina': 'Brazil', 'Pacific/Gambier': 'French Polynesia', 'America/Puerto_Rico': 'Puerto Rico', 'America/Halifax': 'Canada', 'Asia/Pyongyang': "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", 'America/Miquelon': 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', 'Africa/Maseru': 'Lesotho', 'America/Thunder_Bay': 'Canada', 'Europe/Dublin': 'Ireland', 'Europe/Moscow': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Pago_Pago': 'American Samoa', 'America/New_York': 'United States', 'Africa/Kampala': 'Uganda', 'Africa/Mogadishu': 'Somalia', 'Africa/Blantyre': 'Malawi', 'America/Argentina/Mendoza': 'Argentina', 'Europe/Sofia': 'Bulgaria', 'America/Nome': 'United States', 'Indian/Mayotte': 'Mayotte', 'Europe/Warsaw': 'Poland', 'Asia/Almaty': 'Kazakhstan', 'Pacific/Apia': 'Samoa', 'America/Kentucky/Louisville': 'United States', 'America/Winnipeg': 'Canada', 'America/Nipigon': 'Canada', 'Pacific/Nauru': 'Nauru', 'Asia/Seoul': 'Korea, Republic of', 'America/Menominee': 'United States', 'America/Argentina/Cordoba': 'Argentina', 'America/Rainy_River': 'Canada', 'Pacific/Majuro': 'Marshall Islands', 'America/Porto_Velho': 'Brazil', 'Asia/Vientiane': "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 'Europe/Guernsey': 'Guernsey', 'America/North_Dakota/Center': 'United States', 'Africa/Lusaka': 'Zambia', 'Pacific/Kwajalein': 'Marshall Islands', 'America/Port-au-Prince': 'Haiti', 'Europe/Vilnius': 'Lithuania', 'Europe/Vienna': 'Austria', 'Asia/Manila': 'Philippines', 'Africa/Djibouti': 'Djibouti', 'Asia/Jakarta': 'Indonesia', 'Africa/Windhoek': 'Namibia', 'Asia/Macau': 'Macao', 'Africa/Kinshasa': 'Congo, the Democratic Republic of the', 'America/Swift_Current': 'Canada', 'Africa/Lome': 'Togo', 'Asia/Vladivostok': 'Russian Federation', 'America/Belize': 'Belize', 'Europe/Amsterdam': 'Netherlands', 'Africa/Nouakchott': 'Mauritania', 'Asia/Singapore': 'Singapore', 'Europe/Riga': 'Latvia', 'Europe/Berlin': 'Germany', 'Africa/Lagos': 'Nigeria', 'Australia/Broken_Hill': 'Australia', 'America/Pangnirtung': 'Canada', 'Asia/Omsk': 'Russian Federation', 'Europe/Tallinn': 'Estonia', 'Africa/Bujumbura': 'Burundi', 'America/Managua': 'Nicaragua', 'Africa/Bissau': 'Guinea-Bissau', 'Europe/Paris': 'France', 'Asia/Rangoon': 'Myanmar', 'Europe/Chisinau': 'Moldova, Republic of', 'Asia/Irkutsk': 'Russian Federation', 'Asia/Hovd': 'Mongolia', 'America/Antigua': 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'America/Rio_Branco': 'Brazil', 'Asia/Srednekolymsk': 'Russian Federation', 'America/Belem': 'Brazil', 'America/Santarem': 'Brazil', 'America/Danmarkshavn': 'Greenland', 'Pacific/Kiritimati': 'Kiribati', 'America/Panama': 'Panama', 'America/Bahia': 'Brazil', 'Asia/Yerevan': 'Armenia', 'America/Indiana/Vevay': 'United States', 'America/Lower_Princes': 'Sint Maarten (Dutch part)', 'Africa/Asmara': 'Eritrea', 'America/Argentina/Ushuaia': 'Argentina', 'Atlantic/Canary': 'Spain', 'Asia/Phnom_Penh': 'Cambodia', 'America/Mazatlan': 'Mexico', 'America/Argentina/Tucuman': 'Argentina', 'Antarctica/Davis': 'Antarctica', 'America/Argentina/La_Rioja': 'Argentina', 'Pacific/Port_Moresby': 'Papua New Guinea', 'Asia/Muscat': 'Oman', 'Pacific/Enderbury': 'Kiribati', 'America/Havana': 'Cuba', 'America/Argentina/Jujuy': 'Argentina', 'Europe/San_Marino': 'San Marino', 'Asia/Kuwait': 'Kuwait', 'Pacific/Fakaofo': 'Tokelau', 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah': 'United States', 'America/Dominica': 'Dominica', 'Antarctica/DumontDUrville': 'Antarctica', 'Atlantic/Stanley': 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)', 'Asia/Tehran': 'Iran, Islamic Republic of', 'Asia/Dushanbe': 'Tajikistan', 'Asia/Bangkok': 'Thailand', 'Africa/Ouagadougou': 'Burkina Faso', 'America/Sao_Paulo': 'Brazil', 'Australia/Lord_Howe': 'Australia', 'Antarctica/Syowa': 'Antarctica', 'Europe/Oslo': 'Norway', 'Asia/Tashkent': 'Uzbekistan', 'America/Phoenix': 'United States', 'Antarctica/Vostok': 'Antarctica', 'Europe/Istanbul': 'Turkey', 'Asia/Khandyga': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Tarawa': 'Kiribati', 'Australia/Hobart': 'Australia', 'Pacific/Easter': 'Chile', 'Europe/Monaco': 'Monaco', 'America/Juneau': 'United States', 'Europe/Skopje': 'Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of', 'Australia/Darwin': 'Australia', 'America/Sitka': 'United States', 'America/Denver': 'United States', 'Asia/Kuching': 'Malaysia', 'Asia/Makassar': 'Indonesia', 'America/Hermosillo': 'Mexico', 'Asia/Hong_Kong': 'Hong Kong', 'Asia/Kolkata': 'India', 'Asia/Brunei': 'Brunei Darussalam', 'Asia/Anadyr': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Rarotonga': 'Cook Islands', 'America/La_Paz': 'Bolivia, Plurinational State of', 'America/Martinique': 'Martinique', 'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem': 'United States', 'America/St_Barthelemy': 'Saint Barthélemy', 'Europe/Samara': 'Russian Federation', 'Asia/Dubai': 'United Arab Emirates', 'Africa/Johannesburg': 'South Africa', 'America/Blanc-Sablon': 'Canada', 'Indian/Comoro': 'Comoros', 'Asia/Kamchatka': 'Russian Federation', 'Asia/Ulaanbaatar': 'Mongolia', 'America/St_Johns': 'Canada', 'Europe/Bucharest': 'Romania', 'Pacific/Auckland': 'New Zealand', 'Africa/Luanda': 'Angola', 'Africa/Algiers': 'Algeria', 'Asia/Shanghai': 'China', 'America/Creston': 'Canada', 'America/Argentina/Salta': 'Argentina', 'America/Nassau': 'Bahamas', 'America/Dawson': 'Canada', 'America/Yakutat': 'United States', 'Antarctica/Casey': 'Antarctica', 'Europe/Podgorica': 'Montenegro', 'America/Manaus': 'Brazil', 'America/Atikokan': 'Canada', 'America/Recife': 'Brazil', 'Africa/Bamako': 'Mali', 'America/Vancouver': 'Canada', 'Indian/Kerguelen': 'French Southern Territories', 'Indian/Mauritius': 'Mauritius', 'Europe/Mariehamn': 'Åland Islands', 'Europe/Lisbon': 'Portugal', 'Antarctica/Troll': 'Antarctica', 'Europe/Budapest': 'Hungary', 'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos': 'Argentina', 'Australia/Melbourne': 'Australia', 'Europe/Belgrade': 'Serbia', 'Asia/Ust-Nera': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Tongatapu': 'Tonga', 'Pacific/Pohnpei': 'Micronesia, Federated States of', 'Europe/Zagreb': 'Croatia', 'Asia/Karachi': 'Pakistan', 'Africa/Tunis': 'Tunisia', 'America/Merida': 'Mexico', 'Europe/Tirane': 'Albania', 'America/Anchorage': 'United States', 'Europe/Busingen': 'Germany', 'America/Montevideo': 'Uruguay', 'America/El_Salvador': 'El Salvador', 'Europe/Volgograd': 'Russian Federation', 'Pacific/Kosrae': 'Micronesia, Federated States of', 'Africa/Khartoum': 'Sudan', 'America/Santiago': 'Chile', 'Europe/Andorra': 'Andorra', 'Atlantic/Azores': 'Portugal', 'Europe/Minsk': 'Belarus', 'Asia/Colombo': 'Sri Lanka', 'Asia/Dhaka': 'Bangladesh', 'Pacific/Guadalcanal': 'Solomon Islands', 'Asia/Choibalsan': 'Mongolia', 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires': 'Argentina', 'Arctic/Longyearbyen': 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen', 'America/Chihuahua': 'Mexico', 'Indian/Cocos': 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', 'Australia/Adelaide': 'Australia', 'Pacific/Midway': 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', 'Pacific/Guam': 'Guam', 'Africa/Casablanca': 'Morocco', 'Africa/Abidjan': "Côte d'Ivoire", 'Indian/Reunion': 'Réunion', 'Europe/Gibraltar': 'Gibraltar', 'America/Tijuana': 'Mexico', 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh': 'Viet Nam', 'Africa/Ndjamena': 'Chad', 'America/Montserrat': 'Montserrat', 'America/Resolute': 'Canada', 'Pacific/Marquesas': 'French Polynesia', 'Pacific/Galapagos': 'Ecuador', 'Atlantic/Faroe': 'Faroe Islands', 'America/Costa_Rica': 'Costa Rica', 'Asia/Beirut': 'Lebanon', 'America/Whitehorse': 'Canada', 'Africa/Nairobi': 'Kenya', 'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam': 'Tanzania, United Republic of', 'America/Godthab': 'Greenland', 'Asia/Damascus': 'Syrian Arab Republic', 'America/Toronto': 'Canada', 'America/Indiana/Vincennes': 'United States', 'Antarctica/McMurdo': 'Antarctica', 'Indian/Antananarivo': 'Madagascar', 'America/Jamaica': 'Jamaica', 'America/Barbados': 'Barbados', 'Asia/Novosibirsk': 'Russian Federation'}


for _tz, coun in coun_to_tz.items():
    tz = timezone(_tz)
    dt = utc.astimezone(tz)
    if str(dt.time()) == "10:00:00":
         print(dt.strftime("%A %B %d at %I:%M:%S%p in {}".format(coun)))
```

Output:

```
Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Mauritania

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Antarctica

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Liberia

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Sierra Leone

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Sao Tome and Principe

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Mali

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Guinea

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Senegal

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Gambia

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Togo

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Iceland

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Portugal

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Burkina Faso

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Western Sahara

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Côte d'Ivoire

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Greenland

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Morocco

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Ghana

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Guinea-Bissau

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha

Thursday August 22 at 10:00:00AM in Greenland
```